# Using WinSCP transfer files from Linux to Windows

Tags: linux, windows, winscp

I have created a bat file to transfer some log files from a remote linux server to the windows system. `WinSCP.com user:password@192.168.1.1 "get /var/sys/log"` But it doesnt seem to copy. Is the command wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the command is wrong.

The main problem is that you are missing `/command` parameter before `get`.

But there are lot of other deficiencies.

You should start by reading the guide to [automating file transfers from FTP server with WinSCP](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/guide_automation).